# Return variables on the same line - Python

Tags: python, list, return

I've got a for loop which iterates through three elements in a list: ["123", "456", "789"].
So, with the first iteration, it will perform a calculation on each digit within the first element, then add the digits back up. This repeats for the other two elements. The outputs are then converted into strings and outputted.

```
for x in digits:
    if len(x) == 3:
        result1 = int(x[0]) * 8 ** (3 - 1)
        result2 = int(x[1]) * 8 ** (2 - 1)
        result3 = int(x[2]) * 8 ** (1 - 1)

        result = result1 + result2 + result

        decimal = []
        decimal.append(result)

        string = " ".join(str(i) for i in decimal)

        return string
```

Problem is, when outputting the results of the calculations, it outputs them on separate lines, but I need them to be on the same line.

For example:

- 123
- 456
- 789

I need them to be like this:

- 123 456 789

I've tried putting the results of the calculations into a list, which is then converted to a string and outputted, but no dice - it still returns the values on separate lines instead of one.

EDIT:

I know how to do this using the print function:

```
print(str(result), end=" ")
```

But need to use the return function. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the `print` function, you'll see that it has an `end` parameter.

Comment: join the output in a string and print that string

Comment: You'll have to show us the code (or a simple version) to see what the problem is. A common solution is to "join". Suppose you have a list of integers `foo = [1, 2, 3]`. You could convert them to strings, and have them separated with spaces by `" ".join(str(v) for v in foo)`.

Comment: thanks for replying everyone, I've tried what @tdelaney suggested (see updated question), but it still results in the values being outputted on separate lines.

Comment: You have a `return` statement in a for loop - that is either wrong or you haven't shown the whole function and how the function is being used. Please read [mre] and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the list and returning the result inside the `for` instead of outside. You only make a single calculation and return.

```
def foo(digits):
    results = []
    for x in digits:
        if len(x) == 3:
            result1 = int(x[0]) * 8 ** (3 - 1)
            result2 = int(x[1]) * 8 ** (2 - 1)
            result3 = int(x[2]) * 8 ** (1 - 1)
            results.append(result1 + result2 + result3)
    return " ".join(str(i) for i in results)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append each variable on a list using `a_list.append('variable')` and print it using `' '.join(a_list)`
whenever needed.

Comment: Tried doing this, but produced an error. used this instead: (still outputs on separate lines)   

decimal = []
            decimal.append(result)

            string = " ".join(str(i) for i in decimal)

Comment: It throws error because contents of the list are integers.  join()  works only with strings. You can use print(*list, sep=" ") for integers if you dont want to turn them into strings.